# Restrict a particular Account

Tags: validation-rule

I have a account record which can not be edited by anyone except for 2 profiles lets say profile 1 and profile 2. So I have written a validation rule on the account which goes as followed:

```
Id = 'AccountId(Which can not be edited)' && ($User.ProfileId <>'Profile1.Id'  || $User.ProfileId <> 'Profile2.Id') && ISCHANGED (LastModifiedDate)
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

`$User.ProfileId <>'Profile1.Id'  && $User.ProfileId <> 'Profile2.Id'`

use and instead of or. So it should be

```
Id = 'AccountId(Which can not be edited)' && $User.ProfileId <>'Profile1.Id'  && $User.ProfileId <> 'Profile2.Id'
```

Comment: You can remove the brackets around the profile checks as well, as they're now redundant due to the fact it's all AND

Comment: The LastModifiedDate bit might also not work, since I believe that field is not set until after validation rules.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes I think the validation rule still work without it.

Comment: Very true. Its still not working since then Last modified is creating issues.

Comment: any other way to do?

Comment: @NikitaGandhi when you update or create record this validation will always fire. Can you please let me know what is not working here for you.

Answer (score 1):

The downside to using a validation rule here is that a validation rule will consume some CPU time for every Account that undergoes a DML operation (insert, update, delete, undelete). Most of the time, the additional CPU time doesn't amount to much, but it can impact the ability of your org to run at scale.

A validation rule can be made to work for this situation, but that's not the only solution.

You could, for example, create a new `RecordType` specifically for your restricted Account.

For sake of example, let's call this new record type `Restricted`. You can assign this new record type to your two target profiles. This would still allow everyone read access to your restricted account, but creating a new restricted account, or editing an existing restricted account is only possible for the two profiles that have been assigned the `Restricted` record type.

This behavior is documented in [How is Record Type Access Specified](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&language=en). It should be noted, though, that if a profile has the `modify all` permission for a given sObject, it doesn't matter if they don't have access to the record type; they'll always be able to edit all records for that sObject.

The advantage to this approach is that you don't waste any CPU time on evaluating a validation rule for all Accounts that aren't your specially restricted Account. It's also easy to add and remove restricted accounts.

The downside to this approach is that record types are much more of a pain to manage than a validation rule. And, as mentioned earlier, the existing permissions for your org can undermine this solution.

Perhaps an easier way to manage this solution would be to create a permission set, and ensure that the permission set is the only thing allowed to use the `Restricted` record type. Permission sets can be assigned/removed from individual users.